# How to create an array from a "tag input"?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a form and I want to create a filter based on an array that comes from a "tag input".

Using some frontend frameworks I already got an Input that shows tags using the following code:

[image]

```
<form action="/tags" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label">Tags</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text"  data-role="tagsinput" ></input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Which other properties I must include in HTML and how it works on the JS code side? I expect to store each "tag" as an element of an array on some variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery tagsinput plugin, you can access the value using

```
$("#tagsinput").val()
```

This will return a string with each value separated by comma. eg:- `hello,tag2`

To get an array from it, you can call the string split function.

```
const valuesArray = $("#tagsinput").val().split(",");
```

Your html would look like

```
<form id="tagsform" action="/tags" method="POST">
        <input
          id="tagsinput"
          type="text"
          value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo"
          data-role="tagsinput"
          placeholder="Add tags"
        />
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        <div id="array"></div>
      </form>
```

And JS would look like

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#tagsform").on("submit", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const valuesArray = $("#tagsinput").val().split(",");
        $("#array").html(JSON.stringify(valuesArray));
        console.log(values);
      });
    </script>
```

See the below SO Snippet for full code and click Run  to see it in action.

```js
$("#tagsform").on("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const values = $("#tagsinput").val().split(",");
  $("#array").html(JSON.stringify(values));
  console.log(values);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!-- JQuery and tagsinput plugin -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div style="width: 70%; margin: auto;">
  <form id="tagsform" action="/tags" method="POST">
    <input id="tagsinput" type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Add tags" />
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    <div id="array"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```